# Add dropdown for a specific cell in a datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to add different controls to cells in the same column.  The drop down does not show and there is no visible setter:

```
private void AddBooleanDropDown(DataGridView grid, int row, KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp)
{
    DataGridViewComboBoxCell dropDownCell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
    dropDownCell.DataSource = new string[] { "True", "False" };

    grid.Rows[row].Cells["Value"] = dropDownCell;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is very good [MSDN Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx).

> The **DataGridView** control provides several column types, enabling your users to enter and edit values in a variety of ways. If these column types do not meet your data-entry needs, however, you can create your own column types with cells that host controls of your choosing. To do this, you must define classes that derive from **DataGridViewColumn** and **DataGridViewCell**. You must also define a class that derives from Control and implements the **IDataGridViewEditingControl** interface.

Comment: I saw that example.  DataGridViewComboBoxCell already inherits from DataGridViewCell so it should work.  What am I missing?

Comment: I think I got you wrong here. Do you want different controls in one cell?

Comment: I will be adding different controls in the same column.  Later I will be adding a mask edit control for a different cell in the same column.

Comment: Yes you can do that. Just take the example of MSDN. For Text bound cell in the column you have to inherit from `DataGridViewTextBoxCell`. You can create custom cells like `CalendarCell` in the example.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this will be helpful to you, but maybe an alternative method?

I wanted to be able to update an excel spreadsheet that I read into a DataGridView and give the user a few options. I used a ContextMenuStrip that would display on a MouseClick event.

It displays a small menu when you right click on a cell:

[image: Priority dropdown]

If it's not what you're looking for at all, sorry; just perhaps an alternate solution:

```
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //Change Priority Strip
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ContextMenuStrip changePriority = new ContextMenuStrip();
        ToolStripMenuItem highPriority = new ToolStripMenuItem("High Priority");
        changePriority.Items.Add(highPriority);
        highPriority.Click += new EventHandler(changePriorityHighEvent);
        ToolStripMenuItem normalPriority = new ToolStripMenuItem("Normal Priority");
        changePriority.Items.Add(normalPriority);
        normalPriority.Click += new EventHandler(changePriorityNormalEvent);
        ToolStripMenuItem lowPriority = new ToolStripMenuItem("Low Priority");
        changePriority.Items.Add(lowPriority);
        lowPriority.Click += new EventHandler(changePriorityLowEvent);
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        private void gridView_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)                                //On Right Click
            {
                DataGridView.HitTestInfo hit = gridView.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);     //Get the clicked cell
                if (e.RowIndex < 0)                                            //If it's a header, ignore
                    return;
                gridView.CurrentCell = gridView[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];    //Select the cell for future info
                if (gridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 6)                     //If this is the priority column
                {
                    changePriority.Show(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y); //Show the strip
                }
             }
         }

         private void changePriorityHighEvent(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
             //make changes
         }
         private void changePriorityNormalEvent(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
             //make changes
         }
         private void changePriorityLowEvent(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
             //make changes
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can change a specific cell in a grid unless it's the same type.
You could try adding a new column of combo boxes all with that data source

```
var newCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
{
       DataSource = new string[] { "True", "False" }
};

grid.Columns.Add(newCol);
```

also you might want to check that the int your passing in isn't greater than the number of rows.